# add panel on desktop using lightdm

Tags: 16.04, panel

How can I add a new panel on the desktop under Ubuntu 16.04 and lightdm.

Background: I don't like Unity and I want to have an additional panel on my second screen. Unfortunately I can't find any "add panel" in any context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that lightdm was not the full answer.

`cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`
was giving me /usr/sbin/lightdm.
But now I found the following tips:

```
alexandrez@ubuntu:~$ wmctrl -m
  Name: Compiz
  Class: N/A
  PID: N/A
  Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
alexandrez@ubuntu:~$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
  gnome-flashback-compiz
alexandrez@ubuntu:~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
  GNOME-Flashback:Unity
```

And then I found out, that it's not enough to hold the ALT key while right-clicking on an existing panel.
I need to press ALT + WINDOWS + right-click to have a proper context menu.